# Redirecting denied connections to ports 80, 443 to other IP that hosts an error page

Tags: debian, iptables, redirect, ufw, deny

Okay, here we go.. I am using UFW on my Debian 8 server to block all incoming connections on ports 80 and 443, except for those that I have allowed. However, I need to redirect those dropped connections to another IP address (which hosts a website), letting those people know that their connection was denied.
I know that there is not a way of doing that with UFW, but can it be done with iptables? (Or any other way for that matter.. I thought iptables could allow that)
Note that I do not want to use squid poxy for authentication, mainly because it does not support SNI (for https connections), and is too complicated and extensive for the purpose I have (overkill).

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are your web servers NAT'ed behind your Debian server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want send a visible message to people connecting to your 80 or 443 ports, you need a web server for sending that message. Firewalls only handle restrictions on layer 3 / layer 4. http / https is a layer 7 protocol, and firewall doesn't provide any implementation for that.

So, your option here is to implement this "blocking" behaviour on your web server, which handles the contents for allowed addresses.

Comment: Ahh, depends on the firewall. Some firewalls does indeed support the http protocol, via so-called "deep packet inspection", I don't wanna think about what that does to your connection speeds and CPU usage, though, but the Chinese government is famously doing it on a massive scale

Comment: What extra value would inspecting http protocol bring to the great firewall, when they can simply block IP addresses of web sites?

Comment: in order to know which ips to block, they first need to know which ips is badmouthing the chinese government, or running proxies, etc

Comment: here's an interesting read on trying to bypass the great firewall: http://blog.zorinaq.com/my-experience-with-the-great-firewall-of-china/

Comment: The great firewall is of course an interesting topic, but it is off-topic here. And actually the comments are off-topic, since the question was about returning an answer, not simply inspecting which is a different thing.